# Using product image to direct to the product detail

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am trying to use the image control that i have created earlier to direct the image to product details page when the image is clicked:

```
ProductDetail.aspx?ProductId={0} )
```

The below code simply is the way I display the image and bind it into my image control. This is my aspx.cs:

```
protected string GetProductImgUrl(int productId)
    {
        var sqlText = "SELECT pProductImage FROM Products WHERE pProductId = " + productId.ToString();
        using (var mDB = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            mDB.Open();
            var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, mDB);
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (rdr.Read())
                {
                    return ResolveUrl((rdr["pProductImage"]).ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        return ResolveUrl("~/images/NotAvailable.png");     // Not available image
    }
```

This is my mark-up :

```
 <div class="imagesfloat" >
     <img width="100" height="100" src='<%= GetProductImgUrl(3) %>' alt="" />
 </div>
```

The logic is the same in when I use gridview control where I get URl from data field `ProductId` and the URL format string `ProductDetail.aspx?ProductId={0}`

However, for this case I am not using the GridView control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your image tag in an anchor tag

```
 <div class="imagesfloat" >
     <a href="productdetails.aspx?productdetid=3">
        <img width="100" height="100" src='<%= GetProductImgUrl(3) %>' alt="" />
     </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try JS onClick and a small redirect function like this

```
<div class="imagesfloat" >
         <img width="100" height="100" onclick='goToProductPage(3);' src='<%= GetProductImgUrl(3) %>' alt="" />
</div>
```

And a JS function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goToProductPage(prodId){
    window.location = "ProductDetail.aspx?ProductId="+prodId;
}
</script>
```